# Как очистить столбец от непечатных символов так, чтобы остались только буквы и пробелы?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Где-то в строках столбца `ФИО` засели символы, которые мне не удается вычистить.

То есть удается только удалив и все пробелы заодно. Между Фамилией, именем, и отчеством должны быть одинарные пробелы.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("ФИО",'\s') FROM MyTable;
```

Comment: Всегда надо приводить пример данных и желаемый результат. А то не совсем понятно, что вы имеете ввиду. Например, _засели символы, которые мне не удается вычистить_, какие символы, почему не удаётся?

Answer (score 2):

Вот как звучит вопрос, так и делайте: от символов `[` не `^` печатных `[:print:]`, получится:

```
select 
    '>>'||"ФИО"||'<<' "ФИО", '>>'||regexp_replace ("ФИО", '[^[:print:]]+')||'<<' "ФИО" 
from (
    select chr(9)||'Иванов '||chr(10)||'Иван Иваныч'||chr(7) "ФИО" from dual)
/

ФИО                       ФИО                   
------------------------- ----------------------
>>  Иванов                  >>Иванов Иван Иваныч<<
Иван Иваныч<<
```